# I am trying to execute multiple ng-repeat so that I can access a third level array in my json and display in a table but can't get this working

Tags: angularjs, json, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to nest ng-repeat but looks like I am not doing it correctly.
I need all the lineItem in the json to be displayed.

Since, json value I am trying to display is a 3rd level array, I tried nested 
ng-repeat but does not work.

```
    <table border="1" width="100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Id</th>
    <th>materialNumber</th>
    <th>quantity</th>
  </tr>
  <tbody ng-repeat="subConfig in values.subConfigs.subConfig">
    <tr ng-repeat="lineItem in subConfig.lineItems.lineItem">
         <td>{{lineItem.lineItemId}}</td>
         <td>{{lineItem.materialNumber}}</td>
          <td>{{lineItem.quantity}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

[here is jsfiddle I tried:](https://jsfiddle.net/waLvc49x/12/)

Comment: Please see the json in the fiddle link given. Didn't put that here to keep it clean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your json was not in correct format values should not be array also you need to change `ng-repeat="s in values.subConfigs.subConfig">` to `ng-repeat="s in values.configBOM.subConfigs.subConfig">`

Something like

```
<tbody ng-repeat="s in values.configBOM.subConfigs.subConfig">
    <tr ng-repeat="lineItem in s.lineItems.lineItem">
         <td>{{lineItem.lineItemId}}</td>
         <td>{{lineItem.materialNumber}}</td>
          <td>{{lineItem.quantity}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
```

[Here is working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/waLvc49x/14/)

Comment: Thanks Jitender. new to UI and somehow missed this.

Answer (score 0):

Its a very minor mistake  :

Please change your json to an object  instead of an array , the format you have given is wrong .

So it should be :

```
$scope.values={} //whatever you want to write inside
```

instead of:

```
$scope.value=[];
```

Secondly while you are doing ng-repeat you have to change this line  :

```
 <tbody ng-repeat="subConfig in values.subConfigs.subConfig">
```

to :

```
 <tbody ng-repeat="subConfig in values.configBOM.subConfigs.subConfig">
```